# Is there a way to get how much code was parsed and executed in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

Some API where I could verify my app is loading X bytes of JS code. I know there are plugins for VS Code that can show you how big an import is, but these don't account for your own code.
Does anyone know of such an API?
I mean I could just hook into internal `require` and monkey patch it, and count the bytes myself, but I'd like to avoid doing it like this.

Comment: I'd use a code coverage tool like Istanbul (you need to write Mocha unit tests to get it to work though). Code coverage tools will tell you what percent of your code your unit tests execute

Comment: I know about code coverage tools, but that's not what I need. I'd like to get just one number as output, representing bytes of source code parsed and executed.